# How to upload a profile picture using a form post to slim framework accepting and moving the file to a folder?

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am using a form that posts a profile picture, then a functions file which parses the data and sends it to a rest service which is developed with the slim framework.

Here is my code:

form.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo url('functions.php'); ?>" method="post" class="validate form-horizontal">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_settings">

<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span class="colordanger">*</span>Profile picture</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="file" name="profile_picture" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->profile_picture; ?>" data-rule-required="true">
                        <span class="help-block">Upload your profile picture here</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text='<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Saving...'><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

functions.php:

```
case 'save_account_settings':


try {

                $input = array (
                "profile_picture" => "@" . post('profile_picture')
                );

                $extension = '/save_account_settings';
                $result = process_api_put($input,$base_url,$extension);
                msg($result->message, $result->status);

        } 

    catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    msg($e->getMessage(), "danger");
                }



    break;
```

And then rest.php:

```
$app->put("/save_account_settings", function() use ($app)
{
    $input = $app->request()->getBody();
  $input = json_decode($input);
    try {
        if ($input->username && $input->email) 
        {
            //save the file
            $file_extension = pathinfo($input->profile_picture, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $server_file_address = realpath('./') . '/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $_SESSION['id'] . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . $file_extension;
            move_uploaded_file( $input->profile_picture, $server_file_address );
            //save to database
            $users = Model::factory('Users')->where('id', $_SESSION['id'])->find_one();
            $users->set('profile_picture', '/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $_SESSION['id'] . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . $file_extension);
            $users->save();

        $status = "success";
        $message = 'Your settings have been saved successfully.';
        }
        else
        {
            $status = "danger";
            $message = 'Some error has occured. Please try again.';
        }

    } 

    catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                $status = "danger";
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
    $response = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );
    $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);

});
```

It saves the filename in the database but doesnot save the file in the uploads directory. Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be documented yet, but Slim 3 has an [UploadedFile](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/UploadedFile.php) class that seems to handle a lot of file-upload related tasks.  You might consider upgrading to Slim 3 if possible.